# A riddle for 2017

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Inspired by [a riddle for 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087999/a-riddle-for-2015), I'm interested in the problem of representing the number 2017 using the numbers 
$$ 1 \quad 2 \quad 3 \quad 4 \quad 5 \quad 6 \quad 7 \quad 8 \quad 9 
$$
writtend down in this order, and the basic arithmetic operations $+, - \times, \div$, as well as parentheses.

It is fairly easy to find a such solution, such as:
$$ 
 - 1 + 2 + (3 × (4 + 5) − 6 + 7) × 8 × 9 = 2017
$$

How many such solutions exist? What is the simplest one (with reference to some reasonable notion of complexity)?

Comment: Would a brute force answer suffice? Or are you more interested in a general approach?

Comment: please check this question (https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47392/10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2017)

Comment: @Dando18: I don't think there is a general solution to this kind of problem (but I'd be very happy to be proved wrong!)

Comment: @W.R.P.S Thanks! Related, but not the same.

Comment: 1+(2-3+4-5+6)×7×8×9=2017.

Comment: Seems quite amenable to trying all possible combinations and building a list of all possible values that can be so represented.

Answer (score 1):

i found this:
$$1+(-2+3+4+5-6)\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9=2017$$